# Finding probabilities given a small amount of data in the situation

Tags: probability

A survey found that 79% of children like chocolate, 63% like cheese and 59% like chicken.

a) What is the highest possible value for the percentage of children that don't like any of the three?

b) What is the lowest possible value for the percentage of children that like all three of the foods?

c) What is the highest possible value for the percentage of children that like exactly one of the foods?

I have absolutely no idea how we would work these out with the information given. I don't feel like I've been given enough information.

Comment: Draw a venn diagram.

Comment: But how do we know the values of the overlaps?

Comment: `A:` $\min(100-79,100-63,100-59)$. `B:` $\min(79,63,59)$.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at this question and believe I know the answers to part a and part b. However I'm stuck on how to calculate part c.

Part a) Consider this as three Venn diagram bubbles, the totals of which are constant. Then the figures are saying that 79% of children must like chocolate. As the other Venn bubbles are smaller percentages then it is possible that these bubbles could fit entirely within the category of children liking chocolate. This would give an answer of 21%.

Part b) This can be solved using the Inclusion Exclusion principle provided in the following wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

We know the individual percentages for each category. For each paired category, as we are looking for the minimum percentage of people who like all three then we want minimum overlapping for the three pairings. This will leave us an equation to solve for children who like all three. I believe this equals 1%.

I hope this information is helpful

Answer (score -1):

There must be an overlap of at least 42% between those who like chocolate and those who like cheese, otherwise the total percentage would be greater than 100%.  The maximum overlap between these to is 63%, obtained if everyone that likes cheese also likes chocolate. Reason similarly with the other cases.

Comment: How did you get 42%?

Comment: 79%  +62% = 142%, 42% too much

Comment: Hm but then using that logic the overlap between all three is 101%

Comment: Note the overlap must be at least 42%.  Drawing a 3 circle Venn diagrams as Batman suggested should help you to reason it out.

Comment: I have tried to but I don't really know what goes in the overlaps. I know P(chocolate), P(cheese), P(Chicken) but I don't know P(Chocolate and Cheese), P(Chocolate and Chicken), P(Cheese and Chicken) or P(chocolate and cheese and chicken) which is what I need to find. I have no idea how to find them